# How to check if a user has a specific role in a list of roles? (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

When try to run this code nothing happens. no error aswell btw. I got a list of roles to get this to work but it didn't.

```py
rolelist = [822428355554312212,
            822728446059741218,
            823814683973779488]

check = ''

if rolelist in user.roles:
    check += 'Bot Developer'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is missing a lot of information. Please look at ["how to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to improve your question. Add every information you have that might help us, but keep it as short as possible. If you have a question about code, please include the code. You can also take this short [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn more about Stack Overflow.

Comment: `if any(role in user.roles for role in rolelist)`

Comment: To add to @Benjin's answer, you can also do `set(user.roles).intersection(rolelist)` to find the elements that are contained in both `user.roles` and `rolelist`.

Comment: or (if using python>3.7) `set(user.roles) & set(rolelist)`

Comment: @Benjin I tried your sample but it still dosen't work as intended. no error aswell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```py
if any(role.id in rolelist for role in user.roles):
   ...
```

> Well, what does it do?

Per iteration, it gets a role from a user, gets the ID, and checks if the ID is in the `rolelist` array. If the role id is in the array, it stops the loop and executes the function it's supposed to do inside the if statement.

Have a good day!

Comment: thank you for the sample and the explaination! It worked out as intended and I really appreiceate it! (sorry for my mispelling. I'm not that fluent.)

Answer (score 0):

There's also another way. You can use the built in.

Link to the docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_any_role

Example from the docs:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_any_role('Library Devs', 'Moderators', 492212595072434186)
async def cool(ctx):
    await ctx.send('You are cool indeed')
```